# Why would I ever open a file (std::ifstream) without std::ios::binary?

Tags: c++, fstream

This may properly belong to a different part of Stack Exchange but I don't think so - programmers.se is more about other things.

Getting to the question: There are things you can do with std::ios::binary that you cannot do in text mode (E.g. relative seek) but I cannot find anything to do in text mode that you cannot do in binary mode - even reading the file as text with e.g. std::getline()

So why would I ever open as text? As a perhaps-related question, why not open as binary by default? Whose use-case does that break?

**EDIT Additional information**

Here's what's causing me to ask:

I have a file which is created on a windows system - that is, the line-endings are CR LF.

I am opening it with `std::ifstream` using the `std::ios::binary` flag

I am parsing through the file with `std::getline` and getting exactly the behavior I would expect - getline reads one line at a time.

System: Windows 7 Pro

Compiler: g++ for MINGW32

Comment: Not sure if the standard library does this, but there can be some text encoding bytes and byte order masks at the beginning of a text file. Maybe the standard library interprets them correctly and skips them if opened in text mode? But treats them as non-special bytes in binary mode?

Comment: There used to be this idea that you would read and write "a text file" platform-agnostically. So you want to use whatever line separator is suitable for the platform. For those who use any text editor other than Notepad on Windows, I think this idea has pretty much had its day -- you can write LF only and accept both kinds of linebreak when reading, on any platform. But even if you accept that (which not everyone will), changing the default is a needless incompatibility.

Comment: @medivh: on Windows, opening a file in text mode means that if the file contains `\r\n` it will be read as `\n`. So code that uses the default and expects to see `\n` would be broken. It will instead see `\r\n`. So for example you could end up with a trailing `\r` on a value read from the file, because removing `\n` no longer removes the whole linebreak sequence. It will fail to match the equivalent value *without* the erroneous `\r` from some other source.

Comment: @medivh: so to be clear: because you have some code that works when it sees `\r`, you're almost entirely sure that no valid code exists that would not work when it sees `\r`? I don't think the follows ;-) Or do you mean you don't believe that opening a file that contains `\r` in binary mode will result in the code seeing the `\r` characters? That's easily confirmed with a few lines of test code.

Comment: @medivh He is certainly _not_ wrong.  In the last couple of years, I've had to parse files which were written on Windows, parsing on a Unix machine, and the extra `'\r'` did cause me extra work.

Comment: Who's use case does implicit binary break? It breaks everyone's use case who expects `std::istream::getline` to work. I imagine that is a lot of existing code.

Comment: Of course, the real problems show up on some of the mainframes, where if you open a normal text file in binary, either the open will fail, or there won't be any line feeds (and on some systems, of course, there might be extra garbage at the end).

Comment: @Tim But that's exactly why I'm confused - I am opening files in binary mode and parsing through them with getline and it's working fine.

Comment: @JamesKanze Interesting - I might want to see what happens if I compile and port this code (and these files) to Linux. – medivh 7 mins ago

Comment: @medivh Do you verify that there's no garbage at the end of the line (as you generally should)?  Or do you skip trailing white space before doing this verification?  (Unless I'm mistaken, `'\r'` is considered white space.)  In either case, you'll not see the problem, because the additional `'\r'` is just another trailing white space.  In other cases... you are seeing an extra character, which shouldn't be there.  (Still, in an environment where files are shared, I will generally open with binary, and impose whatever convention is necessary, both on input and output.)

Comment: @medivh If you're talking about files from a mainframe... To get them to a Unix machine, you'll have to use some sort of file transfer program.  Which will probably ask if they are text, since if so, you not only have to open the file differently, you have to transcode EBCDIC to ASCII.

Answer (score 7):

What can you do in text mode that you can't do in binary?  Read
text, for starters.  A file opened in text mode automatically
translates between the `'\n'` character internally, and whatever
the system uses to delimit lines in files externally.  It can
also recognize an arbitrary end of file, even when the
underlying system requires file sizes to be a multiple of some
fixed size.

The choice today is somewhat complicated by the fact that you
often have to access the files from incompatible systems.  If
you have a file system mounted on both Windows and Unix, write
it as text under Windows, and read it as text under Unix, then
you'll see extra characters.  In such cases, it may be 
preferable to read and write binary, and to do the line end
handling yourself, according to whatever conventions you prefer.
Similarly, if the "file" is actually a socket, communicating
with another machine, you'll want to open it in binary, and
handle line endings yourself, according to the requirements of
the protocol.

Comment: "Access the file from incompatible systems" - who furthermore share that file by binary means. If the file is shared by content-aware mechanisms (e.g. SVN), that mechanism may do the relevant conversion for you.

Comment: @MSalters When I said "share", I meant "share".  A shared file system, mounted on several different systems.  That seems to be the usual situation in most places I've worked (when they had any Windows machines).

Comment: @medivh: the behavior you describe in your edit makes sense, but I would expect each line you read to have `\r` at the end of it when the file is open in binary mode. Maybe this doesn't harm your program, but it could harm someone else's. I don't have mingw on hand to check, so I can't tell you what it does in text mode -- on the one hand it's running in Windows so it might respect Windows line breaks. On the other hand it's supposed to provide a vaguely Posix-like environment, and Posix requires that binary mode and text mode are identical.

Comment: @medivh: all the online mentions I can find say that mingw does indeed open in text mode by default. So there should be a difference in the results of `getline`. Whether your particular program actually goes wrong or not because of the extra `\r` in binary mode is another matter.

Comment: @medivh Re compiling for Windows or Unix: most of the libraries try to be a bit agnostic when reading.  When you write `'\n'` under Windows, the system will write two bytes into the file; when you read under Windows, the libraries I know will treat an isolated `'\n'` as if it were preceded by a `'\r'`.  Under Unix, the extra `'\r'` will appear in the line you read; whether that causes problems or not depends on how you parse the line.

Answer (score 2):

Well stdin is opened by default in text mode, this allows the use of for example CTRL + Z to signal EOF so I don't see why you think there is no "need" to have streams opened in anyting except binary mode.